# Some questions about the tables

Tags: tables

I want to create a table as follows.

But I can't achieve the followings:

**Question 1:** In the first row, how to write `$W_{HPETM}$` above the `(approx.)`, I mean

> $W_{HPETM}$
>
> (approx.)

**Question 2:** How to add a thick border to the top and bottom of the table, except for using the `\usepackage{booktabs}`?

[image]

Comment: Regarding the first question: Take a look at the `makecell` package. For example: `\makecell[t]{$W_{HPETM}$ \\(approx.)}`. Regarding the second question: What's the problem with the `booktabs` package?

Comment: Please provide MWE, that we can ease show you, how to solve your problem.

Comment: Dear @leandriis, thank you very much for your answer to my first question. On the other hand, there is no problem with the booktabs package. I just want to learn another methods and to adjust properties of border such as thickness and appearance etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *first question*, as @leandriis mentioned, you have the `makecell` package; which by default centres horizontally and vertically its contents, but can have it left-aligned using`\makecell[l]{...}`.

Another possibility is the `stackengine` package, and, say, the `\Shortstack` command.

For the *second question*, `macell` cell, again, defines `\xhline{thickness}` and `\xcline{a-b}{thickness}`.

There is also the `boldline` package, from the `shipunov` bundle, which defines the `\hlineB{some number}` and `\clineB{number}`, and also, for vertical lines, `V{number}` to be inserted in the table preamble, in the place of `|`. The number is used as a multiplicative coefficient of the default rele thickness (`0.4pt`).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using double `\hline`s to create a thicker line for top and bottom. I have removed the space between the two lines using the command:

```
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}
```

To avoid the the lines collide with the cell content, I add more row space using:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
```

The first seven columns are set as `D`-column, using David Carlisle’s package [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn). You may also use the package [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). The columns are now aligned at the decimal point.

I have defined two commands (`\mcc` and `\mcr`) to align the heading either in centre or to the right, which I use to line the headings above the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array, dcolumn}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\mcr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.1pt}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{@{}D..{1.1}D..{1.2}*{5}{D..{1.9}}rD..{1.10}@{}}

\hline\hline
x                 & t                  & \mcr{$w HPETM$}   & 
\mcr{$WHPTM$}     & \mcc{$w$}          & \mcc{abs.error}   &
\mcc{$\| w_1 \|$} & \mcc{$\| w_2 \|$}  & \mcc{$ \|w_3 \|$} \\
                  &                    & \mcr{(approx.)}   &
\mcr{(approx.)}   & \mcr{(exact sol.)} &                   &
                  &                    &                   \\
\hline
    & 0.1  & 0.304691131  & 0.304691131 & 0.302317425 & 0.002373706 & 0.104031064 & 1.88$E-02$ & 7.49$E-04$  \\
    & 0.11 & 0.319292625 & 0.319292625 & 0.316042418 & 0.003250207 &  0.11443417 & 2.28$E-02$ & 9.97$E-04$   \\ 
0.3 & 0.12 & 0.334319781  & 0.334319781   &  0.329984205  &  0.004335576 &  0.124837277 &  2.71$E-02$ &  1.29$E-03$     \\ 
    & 0.13 & 0.34977709   & 0.34977709   &  0.344120184  &  0.005656906 &  0.135240383 &  3.18$E-02$  &  1.65$E-03$     \\ 
    & 0.14 & 0.365669045  & 0.365669045  &  0.358426914  &  0.007242131 &  0.145643489 &  3.69$E-02$ &  2.05$E-03$     \\ 
\hline
    & 0.1  & 0.276611064  & 0.276611064  &  0.275603147  &  0.001007917 &  9.64$E-02$    &  1.92$E-02$ &  4.91507$E-05$  \\ 
    & 0.11 & 0.29026645   & 0.29026645   &  0.288830839  &  0.001435611 &  0.106061562 &  2.32$E-02$ &  6.54196$E-05$  \\ 
0.4 & 0.12 & 0.304302372  & 0.304302372  &  0.302317425  &  0.001984947 &  0.115703523 &  2.76$E-02$ &  8.49324$E-05$  \\ 
    & 0.13 & 0.318718535  & 0.318718535  &  0.316042418  &  0.002676117 &  0.125345483 &  3.24$E-02$ &  0.000107984  \\ 
    & 0.14 & 0.333514645  & 0.333514645  &  0.329984205  &  0.00353044  &  0.134987443 &  3.76$E-02$ &  0.00013487   \\
\hline
    & 0.1  & 0.249765515  & 0.249765515  &  0.25         &  0.000234485 &  8.87$E-02$    &  1.92$E-02$ &  0.000734094  \\ 
    & 0.11 & 0.262435106  & 0.262435106  &  0.262653581  &  0.000218475 &  9.76$E-02$    &  2.33$E-02$ &  0.00097708   \\
0.5 & 0.12 & 0.275441031  & 0.275441031  &  0.275603147  &  0.000162116 &  0.10646815  &  2.77$E-02$ &  0.001268515  \\
    & 0.13 & 0.288778885  & 0.288778885  &  0.288830839  &  5.19537$E-05$ &  0.115340496 &  3.25$E-02$ &  0.001612806  \\ 
    & 0.14 & 0.302444264  & 0.302444264  &  0.302317425  &  0.000126839 &  0.124212842 &  3.77$E-02$ &  0.0020101455 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.